# How to bring .current to front in moving-boxes plugin

Tags: css, jquery-plugins

Here is the page I'm working on: http://dontapscott.patienceandfortitude.com/about/#&slider1=6

I'm using the [moving boxes plugin from css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/2223-moving-boxes/). I'm trying to figure out how to bring the non-current slides in behind the current one.

As you can see in the default implementation, there's a margin around the slides and I'd like them to overlap instead. I tried this using negative margins and it works to make them overlap, but the next slide remains in front of the current one, despite applying a high z-index to the .current slide and a low one to all others.

Many thanks for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `.current` selector to this:

```
.mb-slider .mb-panel.current {
    cursor: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `position:relative` to your `.current` selector along with the `z-index` that you tried previously.